# Duplicate index warning on sphinx build; How do I include a file without indexing its contents?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I wish to create an `single_html.rst` file that contains all my `class`/`method`/`attribute`/etc... , but also split categorised symbols into seperate pages.

e.g.

#### single_html.rst

```
.. single html

.. include:: foo.rst

.. include:: bar.rst
```

#### bar.rst

```
.. autoclass:: my.mod.Bar
    :members:
```

#### foo.rst

```
.. autoclass:: my.mod.Foo
    :members:
```

This throws multiple `duplicate object description` errors:

> /path/to/project/my/mod.py:docstring of my.module.Bar:0: WARNING: duplicate object description of my.mod.Bar, other instance in /path/to/project/docs/source/api/single_html.rst, use :noindex: for one of them
>
> /path/to/project/my/mod.py:docstring of my.module.Bar:0: WARNING: duplicate object description of my.mod.Foo, other instance in /path/to/project/docs/source/api/single_html.rst, use :noindex: for one of them

I can't simply place `:noindex:` on the `autoclass::` directives as this will remove all the indexes completely. (so there are either duplicate indexes or none at all!)

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid those warnings by changing the extension of included files.

Sphinx considers each `.rst` (by default, it can be changed in the `conf.py` file) as a "source to parse" file. So it will try to parse the `foo.rst` and the `bar.rst` files and find `autodoc` directives for `my.mod.Foo` and `my.mod.Bar`.
When it tried to parse `single_html.rst`, it first include the content of `foo.rst` and `bar.rst`; thus, it then find again the directives for `my.mod.Foo` and `my.mod.Bar`.

By renaming `foo.rst` and `bar.rst` to `foo.inc` and `bar.inc` (of whatever you want as extension), you will prevent Sphinx from parsing the included files and will avoid the warnings.

Comment: This only partially works. When I rename the files, I also invalidate the references to these documents from my main `:toctree:`  `toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'api/bar.txt'` I want to have my cake and eat it too :P

Comment: thank you: useful answer.  but wouldn't it be great if *subdirectories* also counted in that path to make things unique.  I have a book in several parts, and each part has a chapter called "motivation-and-review.rst".  Hierarchy is good, and I wish I did not have to rename things, since they are in subdirectories already.