# Sphinx toctree with automodule

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc, toctree

I have modules I'd like to document such that the table of contents is on the main page `index` and the documentations themselves are in separate pages. I'm new to automatic documentation and Sphinx, but I've gotten close:

```
index.rst:

Documentation
*************

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   Module1
   Module2

Index
=====
* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`

Module1.rst and Module2.rst:

Title
*****

.. automodule:: Module1 (or Module2)
   :noindex:
   :members:
```

The reason for using `noindex` was getting duplicate object description errors. However this prevents the modules from showing up on the `toctree` of `index`. How might this be avoided? It seems like a basic thing one would do but I can't get my head around it.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

It seems [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738852/duplicate-index-warning-on-sphinx-build-how-do-i-include-a-file-without-indexin) and its answer attempts to address a similar problem, but I don't think it's quite the same, as the OP commented on the answer.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [Pyramid documentation](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/tree/master/docs), which has both narrative, API, and automatic documentation of scripts. Also look at [sphinx-apidoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) and [autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html), a process for automatically documenting modules.